# Create database entity field with digit(s)

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, database-schema

I'm trying to add a price field into a custom entity I've created but the digit disapeared and it's rounded.

How to keep 2 digits ?

```
                    ->addColumn(
                        'price_ht',
                        Table::TYPE_FLOAT,
                        null,
                        [
                            Table::OPTION_SCALE => 2
                        ],
                        'Price HT'
                    );
```

This is interpreted as `10,0` in the database instead of (10,2) which would accept digits i guess so the scale option doesn't work.

This is what I have in my form

```
    <field name="price_ht">
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
        </settings>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price HT</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">entity</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">price_ht</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

And this is what I have in my listing

```
    <column name="price_ht">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price HT</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

EDIT : Tried to add precision and same result

```
                    ->addColumn(
                        'price_ht',
                        Table::TYPE_FLOAT,
                        null,
                        [
                            Table::OPTION_SCALE => 2,
                            Table::OPTION_PRECISION => 2
                        ],
                        'Price HT'
                    );
```

Comment: Did you try to set the precision along with the scale as well?

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner Looks like same resultentering 4.750 result in the value 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try precision because scale provide the number of digits after the decimal in a real data type.

Check the below link -

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

Comment: just tried it seems not to work

Comment: End up going threw all taht changing the type from float to decimal AND changing the precision to 10 instead of 2 (miss read the doc).